# Ati Catalyst 9.8 work with old ati cards?

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card

the last drivers for my ati xpress 1150 what 9.3 (.1) why Ati give me 9.8 when I select my card ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's confusing, I know :)

The release notes are for version 9.3, but then the version of the download is 9.8. Doesn't make much sense. However, take a look at the filename of the download. It's **9-8_legacy_vista32-64_dd_ccc.exe** (or **9-8_legacy_xp32-64_dd_ccc.exe**, if that's the OS you chose).

So you are on the right spot and that's what you should download. However...

Take care of the text in that page. If you are running your on-board ATI Xpress 1150 in combination with any of the HD 2000, 3000 or 4000 series you should indeed not download this. You should stick to 9.3.

Otherwise, if Xpress 1150 is your only GPU, then go ahead and download the 9.8 legacy driver. That's what you will want.

(With Ati modder it worked !!!)

Comment: the driver 9.8 (legacy) is said to be incompatible ...