# Where can I get the latest drivers for an ATI Xpress 1150 or similar?

Tags: windows, drivers, amd-radeon

AMD gives me 9.8, Catalyst gives me 9.9... the latest drivers should be 9.3.1 but my card support was dropped with 9.3... Which one should I use?

I'm using Windows XP SP3

Comment: Usually helps to specify the platform details or other related questions you have posted. http://superuser.com/questions/40730/ati-catalyst-9-8-work-with-old-ati-cards

Comment: Great example of how not to get a question answered.  It's really unclear what you're asking, AND you threw in a bunch of unrelated ranting about Windows OSs.

Comment: Learn how to use punctuation, grammar, and capitalization to get an answer on here.  Also, not being prejudice helps a lot of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ATI Catalyst Legacy Display Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Legacy/Pages/integrated_mce-xp.aspx?type=2.7&product=2.7.5.3.1&lang=English) Version 9.8 is the latest released driver that supports your chipset. See the [Release Notes](https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/674/9206/0/www2.ati.com/drivers/Catalyst_93_release_notes.pdf) for the ATI Radeon Xpress 1150 listing.